# Additional Permission required if Java Console is open?

Tags: java, permissions, applet

I've found an interesting behaviour in my Java Applet.

All seems to work fine, but when i have the Java Console Window the Applet does nothing and i can see the following exception to be thrown in the Java Console:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-33" java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "accessClassInPackage.com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.awt.ui")
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPackageAccess(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.SecurityManagerHelper.checkPackageAccessHelper(Unknown Source)
(...)
```

So my question is now, why does the Application need more permissions when the console is open than when its closed? I've tried to google the permission but no one seems to have had any problems with this.